# Dynamic if statement for a given range of conditions and values

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to have a dynamic if-else in python. This is a simple example:

```
def static_if(x):
   if x < 5:
      return 10
   elif x< 10:
      return 20
   elif x<20:
       return 18
   else:
       return -1
```

The return value and the range are constantly changing. Even the number of if-else's that I use may change. I want to have a function with which dynamically capture this output. For instance, given the output array of `[10,20,18,-1]` and the conditions of `[5,10,20]` the above function is created. The length of output and condition may change, but the length of the output is always 1 less than conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function which takes in your condition and output arrays, and then uses them to create a new function which does what your `static_if` does:

```py
def dynamic_if(output, cond):
    def func(x):
        for i, val in enumerate(cond):
            if x < val:
                return output[i]
        return output[-1]

    return func
```

```py
static_if = dynamic_if([10,20,18,-1], [5,10,20])

static_if(4) # will output 10
static_if(21) # will output -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a loop, keeping your conditions and outputs in two lists.

Example:

```
def dynamic_if(number, inputs, outputs):
  for inp in range(len(inputs)):
    if number < inputs[inp]:
      return outputs[inp]
  return outputs[-1]


inputs = [5,10,20]
outputs =[10,20,18,-1]

print(dynamic_if(8,inputs,outputs))
print(dynamic_if(12,inputs,outputs))
```

Output:

```
20
18
```

Comment: The problem that I had with this idea is that it does not work for number greater than 20. (ELSE part)

Comment: The default return is based on the final element in the `outputs` array, not necessarily `-1`. Your last line in the definition should read `return outputs[-1]` :)